# How to remove unspecified number of spaces after a specific word in a sentence in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have below String,
**abcfoobarfoo   def xyzfoobcd fooaaafoo bar**
In this string, I need your help to remove all spaces only after **foo only** if exists.
output: **abcfoobarfoodef xyzfoobcd fooaaafoobar**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And where is your attempt?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
String s="abcfoobarfoo def xyzfoobcd fooaaafoo bar";
String str=s.replaceAll("foo ","foo");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Does not assign to new string. Your second line should be `s = s.replaceAll("foo ","foo");`

Comment: Removes only the first space after 'foo'. Try `replaceAll("foo\\s+","foo");`

Comment: @Robert s.replaceAll("foo ","foo");  is also removing all the spaces and not just the first space.

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal In my test it didn't. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your Answer, it is working fine for above scenario, but need help for another scenario. suppose after foo there is space as well as next word is starting from next line.

Comment: s=s.replaceAll("foo \n","foo"); try this

Comment: PoojaAggarwal, Use regexp as Robert Kock suggested: \\s+ is an alias to all space symbols, like tabs or new lines or just spaces.

Comment: Ok I will try this regx.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String str = "abcfoobarfoo def xyzfoobcd fooaaafoo bar"; 
   String oldStr = "foo ";
   String newStr = "";
   String resultStr;
   resultStr = str.replace(oldStr, newStr);
   System.out.println("resultStr:"+resultStr);
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you please explain your solution code?